# Inheriting a class that uses a Has-A relationship and replacing the owned class with a subclass?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, inheritance

I am using ActionScript3, I am writing a class that extends Bitmap, I want to have all of Bitmap's behaviors and I also want to treat to replace its bitmapData with a subclass of bitmapData that offers more flexibility.

So basically what I have is(metaphor):

```
Class Gunman
{
    //Has-A
    public var pistol : Gun;
    public function Gunman(gun : Gun)
    {
        this.pistol = gun;
    }
    //methods
    public function shoot():void ..
    {
        pistol.fire();
    }  
}

Class Gun
{
    //constructor omitted cause it is unnecessary for this example
    public function fire():void ..
}
```

Now I extend these two classes.

```
Class Automatic extends Pistol
{
    override public function fire():void
    {
        super.fire(); super.fire(); super.fire();
    }
}

Class NavySeal extends Gunman
{
    public function Enforcer(auto : Automatic)
    {
        super(auto);
    }
}
```

The problem is that people can still easily do this:

```
var eliteSoldier : NaveSeal = new Enforce(new Automatic());
eliteSoldier.pistol = new Gun();
```

And this will be bad. Is there any way I prevent this?

I cannot change 'Gunman' cause it is part of the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to prevent from changing public property `public var pistol:Gun;` than you can't if you haven't got the control over the class that has defined it. It is a bad design, it should be the getter/setter instead. Then you would be able to get and test what users are passing etc.

best regards

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, turns out the original class I'm inheriting from uses getters and setters for it's "pistol" and that I can indeed override these methods like you suggested. I am very happy.